# SAS Proc means, storing mean values as variables

Tags: sas

I need to find a ratio of two mean values, that I have found using `proc means`.

```
proc means data=a;
class X Y;
var x1 x2;
run;
```

Then I get the output mean values for variables `x1` and `x2` in the two categories of `X` and `Y`, but it is `x1/x2` for each category that I am interested in, and doing it by hand is not really a solution.

I am not a professional programmer, so I hope there is a simple piece of code that I can understand and use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to precompute x1/x2 or postcompute x1/x2 (Depending on whether you want `mean(x1/x2)` or `mean(x1)/mean(x2)`, which can have different answers of x1 and x2 have different numbers of responses).

So either (... means fill in what you have already)

```
data premean;
set have;
x1x2 = x1/x2;
run;

proc means ... ;
class ... ;
var x1x2;
run;
```

or

```
proc means ...;
class ... ;
var x1 x2;
output out=postmeans mean=;
run;

data want;
set postmeans;
x1x2=x1/x2;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you, Joe's solution works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql noprint;

    create table xy_ratio as /* New table name*/
    select distinct X, Y, avg(x1)/avg(x2) as x1_x2_ratio /* selects distinct rows containing variables listed here. (Must include group by variables) mean of x1 / mean of x2 to form ratio*/
    from a /*source dataset*/
    group by X, Y /*Similar to class statement, will provide an average for each distinct combination of X and Y that appear in the dataset*/
    ;
quit;
```